# Upload Azure Enterprise API append blob as block blob to Storage Account

Tags: c#, azure, blob

I am trying to use a the Azure Enterprise API to do some reporting using HDInsight. However, HDInsight seems to support only block blob format while the file received from Azure API is an append blob.

From the Azure Data Movement library's example code, I am using the following snippet to perform the task of fetching the result from the API to a storage account. However, I need it to a block blob and I am unable to find a solution so far. I have tried using the UploadAsync method but nothing gets uploaded in this case.

```
                    //ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
                    try
                    {

                        task = TransferManager.CopyAsync(uri, blob, true, null, context, cancellationSource.Token);
                        //while (!task.IsCompleted)
                        //{
                        //    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                        //    {
                        //        keyinfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
                        //        if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
                        //        {
                        //            cancellationSource.Cancel();
                        //        }
                        //    }
                        //}
                        await task;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, there is no support for Append Blobs currently in HDInsight. 
You would use [TransferManager.CopyAsync](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/tree/master/samples/DataMovementSamples) to fetch the result from API which is an append blob to a storage account.

After testing, when you copy your blob, you must **make sure their type is the same**. If not, you will get the following error message.

[image]

According to your demands, I suggest that you could **download the append blob** firstly. Then when you **upload blob** to your storage account you could c**hoose block type** of the blob.

Also, you could use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) to achieve it.

Comment: In case of downloading and uploading, will there be a billing impact compared to a simple copy?

Comment: All prices are per GB, per month. Refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/).